# Multiple object instantiation prevention?

Tags: php, oop, object, zend-framework2

I have a class with a private variable used to store an object. 
I have a function that checks first if that variable already contains an object or not; if not, it instantiates the needed object and sets it to that variable, otherwise it just returns the content of that variable.

I was wondering if the `getSessionCustomer()` here is an overkill/unnecessary or if it has real benefits. I simply based this on the Album tutorial by Zend, but I haven't been able to fully test it out yet to really see the advantages (or disadvantages). As far as I know it wasn't explained in the docs why this additional function was included.

```
class JobController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $SessionCustomer;

    public function saveJobAction()
    {
        $SessionCustomer = $this->getSessionCustomer();

        if(empty($SessionCustomer->offsetGet('customer_id'))) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
        } else {
            $JobService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Job\Factory\JobServiceFactory');
            $job_id     = $JobService->saveJob();

            return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/job/' . $job_id); 
        }
    }

    public function viewJobAction()
    {
        $sm                 = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $SessionCustomer    = $this->getSessionCustomer();

        if(empty($SessionCustomer->offsetGet('customer_id'))) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
        } else {
            $JobTable       = $sm->get('Job\Model\JobTable');
            $JobItemTable   = $sm->get('Job\Model\JobItemTable');

            $jobId          = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
            $Job            = $JobTable->getJobById($jobId);
            $JobItems       = $JobItemTable->getJobItemsByJobId($jobId);

            $this->layout()->setVariable('title', 'Order #' . $jobId);

            $viewModel = new ViewModel();
            $viewModel->setVariables(array(
                'Job' => $Job,
                'JobItems' => $JobItems
            ));

            return $viewModel;
        }
    }

    private function getSessionCustomer()
    {
        if(!$this->SessionCustomer) {
            $this->SessionCustomer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Session\Customer');
        }

        return $this->SessionCustomer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it guarantees that there is an object, which will prevent the nasty `call to a member function of a non-object` error.  As far as it being a private variable, AFAIK it's not necessary; it just helps save you from yourself.  I am a little surprised that `Customer` is not being injected; as it's written, I would think it would be harder to test because it looks like `Customer` is hard-coded into the method.

Comment: @TimMorton Thanks! Would using a `JobControllerFactory` class help with injecting `Customer` as a dependency?

Comment: I'll have to defer that answer to more advanced programmers...  I'm not terribly experienced with the factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its an overkill, but I usually avoid calling getServiceLocator() in Controllers.

What you are asking about is basically making sure that the controller's dependency requirement is met. You can use a `Factory` for the same purpose and do this more sophisticated way. You can create a factory and inject the dependencies directly into the controller. This you will never make a call to the non-object variables.

For that you will be required to create a class that implements a `FactoryInterface` which will have a method `createService` which will provide you with `ServiceLocator`. You can use that serviceLocator to get all the dependencies and inject them directly into your Class.